# What does "целый муравейник в поле загонял бы" mean?

Tags: выражения

In the comments to [this video about БК-0010](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8_06bY4wGI), there is a comment

> За такой комп в детстве бы целый муравейник в поле загонял!!!!

I'm given to understand that комп is just short for компьютер, so that makes sense. And I believe the feeling is that the author of this comment coveted these computers as a child.

- За такой комп - "For this kind of computer", or perhaps "At a computer like this one"
- в детстве - "in childhood"
- целый муравейник - "an entire anthill"
- бы в поле загонял - "would have driven into the ground"

So I think I understand all the words, but in all, the entire sentence does not make sense to me. Is there some idiomatic sense to муравейник загоняет? Or is муравейник the object, with the subject being an implied я?

(Apparently муравейник can also mean человейник, but this makes no sense either)

Comment: It's not any kind of phraseological unit  - at least not anything I'm aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a contamination of [*воробья в поле загоняю*](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) with **муравья в поле загоняю*, combined with a hyperbole (*муравья > много муравьёв*), combined with a synecdoche (*много муравьёв > муравейник*)

*Воробья в поле загоняю* means "I'll do whatever it takes (to achieve something)", literally "I'll drive a sparrow to exhaustion in an (open) field". This can also be used as *зайца в поле загоняю, муху в поле загоняю* etc.